# Actualizar datos de tabla MYSQL con datos enviado en JSON (metodo post)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, base-de-datos

Estoy construyendo un CRUD con php,jquery y datos enviados con json.
Pero estoy con un problema que al intentar actualizar los datos de la tabla, me envia un error en consola y no logro actualizar los datos en la tabla y cargarlos en la vista HTML.

Les dejo mi código editar que he creado para la consulta de mysql, no se si esta realmente bien el editar.php, si contiene toda la información necesaria para que se ejecute el método post y envié lo datos correctamente a la tabla mysql.

CODIGO editar.php

```
<?php
include_once('conexion.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$resource = $conn->query($query);
$total = $resource->num_rows;

// UPDATE data
$query = "UPDATE productos SET `nombre` = '$nombre', `descripcion` = '$descripcion', `codigo` = '$codigo', 
`categoria` = '$categoria',`frase_promocional` = '$frase_promocional', `colores` = '$colores', `precio` = '$precio', `disponibilidad` = '$disponibilidad', 
`promocion` = '$promocion', `fecha` = '$fecha'  WHERE id=$id";


while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){
  //print_r($row);
      $row['nombre']=utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
      $row['categoria']=utf8_encode($row['categoria']);
      $row['frase_promocional']=utf8_encode($row['nombre']);
      $row['descripcion']=utf8_encode($row['descripcion']);
  
    $array[] = $row;
   
  }

if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
  echo json_encode($array);
} 
else {
  echo json_encode(array("statusCode"=>201));
}

if(!isset($_POST)){
  $editar = $_POST['editar'];
  echo  $editar;
  exit();
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

CODIGO Jquery envia los datos mediante el metodo post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Abre el Modal
    $('#modalEditar').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
        var identificador = button.data('identificador')
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-body #identificador').val(identificador)
        
       /*  var imagen = button.data('imagen'); */
        var nombre = button.data('nombre')
        var descripcion = button.data('descripcion')
        var codigo = button.data('codigo')
        var categoria = button.data('categoria')
        var frase_promocional = button.data('frase_promocional')
        var colores = button.data('colores')
        var precio = button.data('precio')
        var disponibilidad = button.data('disponibilidad')
        var promocion = button.data('promocion')
        var fecha = button.data('fecha')

        /* modal.find('.modal-body #url-imagen').val(imagen); */
        modal.find('.modal-body #nombre').val(nombre)
        modal.find('.modal-body #descripcion').val(descripcion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #codigo').val(codigo)
        modal.find('.modal-body #categoria').val(categoria)
        modal.find('.modal-body #frase_promocional').val(frase_promocional)
        modal.find('.modal-body #colores').val(colores)
        modal.find('.modal-body #precio').val(precio)
        modal.find('.modal-body #disponibilidad').val(disponibilidad)
        modal.find('.modal-body #promocion').val(promocion)
        modal.find('.modal-body #fecha').val(fecha)
       
      })

    // Editando la base de datos correspondiente
    $('#editar_btn').click(function() {
        console.log("Editando")

        /* var imagen = $('#modalEditar #url-imagen').val(); */
        var nombre = $('#modalEditar #nombre').val()
        var descripcion = $('#modalEditar #descripcion').val()
        var identificador = $('#modalEditar #identificador').val()

        var codigo = $('#modalEditar #codigo').val()
        var categoria = $('#modalEditar #categoria').val()
        var frase_promocional = $('#modalEditar #frase_promocional').val()
        var colores = $('#modalEditar #colores').val()
        var precio = $('#modalEditar #precio').val()
        var promocion = $('#modalEditar #promocion').val()
        var fecha = $('#modalEditar #fecha').val()

        var json = {
            "columnas": ["nombre", "descripcion","codigo","categoria","frase_promocional","colores","precio", "disponibilidad","promocion","fecha"],
            "valores": [nombre,descripcion,codigo,categoria,frase_promocional,colores,precio,disponibilidad,promocion,fecha ],
            "indice": "id",
            "valor_indice": identificador,
            "tabla": "productos",
        }

        // metodo post
        $.post({
            url: 'editar.php', //editar
            data: {'editar': json},
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(respuesta) {
                if (respuesta == 1) {
                    listar_productos();
                    $('#modalEditar').modal('hide')
                } else {
                    console.error("Problemas al editar producto")
                    console.error(respuesta)
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.error("Sin Respuesta editar producto");
            }
        });

        

    });
    
});
```

Comment: En `editar.php` no veo que recuperes los datos que habría en `$_POST` . En `$query` empiezas a usar variables, pero, ¿de donde sacas esas variables? Y, dices que da error, cuando haya un error conviene que lo agregues en la pregunta, el mensaje completo del error.

Comment: ahi arregle el editar con otro codigo, tal vez se entienda mejor..  el erro es : Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Yo me refiero a las variables que usas aquí: `$query = "UPDATE productos SET nombre = '$nombre', descripcion = '$descripcion', codigo = '$codigo', 
categoria = '$categoria', frase_promocional = '$frase_promocional', colores = '$colores', precio = '$precio', disponibilidad = '$disponibilidad', 
promocion = '$promocion', fecha = '$fecha'  WHERE id=$id";` ¿Dónde defines todas esas variables (`$nombre, $descripcion, $codigo`, etc...)?

Comment: Por favor pega el error que te da en consola para darle una idea a la solución

Comment: tendria que actualizarlo a esto :

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
  
    if(is_numeric ($id)){
  
      $query = "UPDATE * productos FROM productos";
  
    }
  }

Comment: Toda la razón, me falta declara las mismas variables mas arriba..